# Characters comparison between two files

Tags: linux, file, comparison, diff

Let's imagine that we have 2 txt files in column format (space is a separator).
1st file:

```
Col1 Col2  Col3
1    1     1
Two  2     2
3    3     3
4    4     4
```

2nd:

```
Col1 Col2  Col3
1    1     One
2    2     2
Test 3     Test
4    4     4
```

Let's compare:

- Row 1. Values in Col3 are different
- Row 2. Values in Col1 are different
- Row 3. Values in Col1, Col3 are different
- Row 4. Values are equal

The question is how to get a list of all columns which differ (Col1 and Col3 in this particular case).
I'm wondering is it possible to reach only using Linux tools like **diff**?

I have found a **wdiff** tool for comparing files on a word per word basis. But I don't know how to use it to resolve my task.

wdiff file1.txt file2.txt

```
1    1 [-1
Two-]     {+One+}
2    2     {+2
Test+} 3 [-3 3-]     {+Test+}
4    4     4
```

Comment: @GillesQuenot Yes, I tried to use wdiff tool

Comment: @GillesQuenot I'm sorry, fixed that

Answer (score 2):

Perl to the rescue!

```
paste file1 file2 \
| perl -lane '
    @cols = @F if 1 == $.;
    $F[$_] eq $F[$_ + @F/2] or ++$h{$_} for 0 .. $#F/2;
    END {print "@cols[keys %h]"}'
```

`paste` prints the files side by side:

```
1    1     1    1    1     One
Two  2     2    2    2     2
3    3     3    Test 3     Test
4    4     4    4    4     4
```

Perl then reads the lines, compares the first column with the fourth and so on, and remembers which columns were different. At the end, it shows the names of the columns where a difference was.

- `-l` removes newlines from output, adds them to `print`
- `-n` runs the code for each line of input
- `-a` splits input on whitespace into the @F array
- `$.` is the input line number. The first line populates the column names array @cols.
- `$#F` is the last index of the array @F. So, we go over the indices of @F from 0 to the half, and for each we compare the columns, and if they are different, we store the index of the column in the %h hash.
- `END` runs at the end. [keys](http://p3rl.org/keys) return the indices of the differing columns, so we map them to their names stored in the @cols array.

Comment: Thanks, mate! Unfortunately, I don't use Perl, but it may be useful for me in the future.

Answer (score 1):

somewhat verbose and long-handed...

```sh
awk '
FNR==1 || !NF {next}
FNR==NR{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
     f1[FNR,i]=$i
  next
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
    if ($i != f1[FNR,i])
     diff[i]
}
END {
  for (i in diff)
    print i
}
' file1 file2
```

similar to perl's approach by @choroba:

```sh
paste file1 file2 | \
   awk '
     {
         for(i=1;i<=NF/2;i++)
           if ($i != $(i+NF/2) )
             diff[i]
     }
     END {
       for (i in diff)
         print i
     }
   '
```

Comment: wow, thanks a lot! a question regarding "FNR" and "NF" abbreviations. what does it mean?

Comment: and "NR" as well

Comment: NF: The number of fields in the current input record; FNR: The input record number in the current input file; NR: The total number of input records seen so far. FNR==NR for the first file to be parsed.

Comment: By the way, the second script with "paste" leads to false last line number printing even when files are equal. But it works faster.

Comment: not for the sample files you provided. What gets output are field numbers - not line/record numbers that have diff values. Care to share you faulty files? Note: it assumes the dimensions of the matrices/tables are the same.

Comment: @vhersh99 I don't know can I share links here or no. I downloaded Excel file from file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/file_example_XLS_5000.xls and then copy output to txt file

Comment: And then just copy it for file2.txt

Comment: worked just fine with the mirror copy of 2 files - nothing to output. Then I changed 6125 to 6125- on the last line/last field - it returned with the last column. Are you sure you don't have Microsoft ^M-s in your file(s) or any other invisible gremlins??

Comment: you better yet, when you save your xls, what field separator do you use? The script assumes the fields are space separated.